# Is there a way to rotate the view after it has loaded completely?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, autorotate, uiinterfaceorientation

I am looking for a way to rotate a view after the view has been load when it has been present as a modal view.

I envoke my view by calling:

```
[self presentModalViewController:cntrol animated:YES];
```

And in that modal view controller i am rotating via:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return  (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a view using a transform.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2);
self.view.transform = transform;
```